# Define an anonymous function without using the `function` keyword

Tags: r, anonymous-function

I can define and use an anonymous function and call it like this

```
x <- 1:3
sapply(x, function(x) x)
```

Sometimes I feel that using `function` like this is too verbose. Is there another way to define an anonymous function?

In the [`purrr` package](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/), one can define an anonymous function like this

```
map(x, ~.x)
```

but this only works in the `purrr` context.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible in base R.  What you're looking for is something along the lines of Lambda syntax which languages like Python and Java have.

Comment: Your code should be readable to other ~humans, and verbosity should be way down the requirements list. Except in java.

Answer (score 8):

#### New in R 4.1.0

> Backslash can now be used as shorthand for creating anonymous functions. For example, `\(x) x + 1` is now parsed as `function(x) x + 1`.

```
sapply(1:3, \(x) x + 1)
# [1] 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 7):

How less verbose could you make it? You need some kind of indicator that this is a function, some way of saying the arguments, and some way of saying the calculation. The only thing that makes it "verbose" is that "function" has eight letters. If you don't want that then define your function **outside** the apply and then you get `sapply(x, foo)` which is concise and descriptive and well-understood without resort to external dependencies (purrrr) or non-standard evaluation.

Comment: but then `sapply` is a lot of characters... maybe redefine with just `s`? but then, brackets and comma?... ;-)

Comment: verbosity is to be encouraged. better to wrap this whole call to `sapply(x, function(x)x)` into a function called `run_identity_function_on_all_elements`

Comment: I couldn't agree more :-)

Comment: I once had the task of debugging code by someone of the habit of using variable names in the style of `a_counter_that_increases_by_one_each_iteration`, I had to copy and paste the variables each time I made a modification. Personally I am from the other extreme, where I think of a sensible name for the variable and then just use the first letter instead, this coupled with my habit of not commenting code causes headaches for others (and occasionally my future self).

Answer (score 7):

**1) gsubfn::fn** The [gsubfn package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gsubfn) supports a formula notation for defining functions and unlike purrr, mentioned in the question, which only works with purrr functions it works with just about any function.

If an anonymous function is passed to another function, in the example the anonymous function is passed to `sapply`, then preface `sapply` with `fn$` and use formula notation of the form args ~ body.  If args are missing then the free variables in the body are assumed to be arguments in the order encountered in the body so in the first example below `z` is assumed to be the single argument.

```
library(gsubfn)

x <- 1:3
fn$sapply(x, ~ z)
## [1] 1 2 3

# same - specify arg
fn$sapply(x, z ~ z)
## [1] 1 2 3

# same - can use any variable name we like
fn$sapply(x, ~ x)
## [1] 1 2 3

# same
sapply(x, function(z) z)
## [1] 1 2 3
```

Anonymous functions can have any number of arguments. The following are all the same:

```
fn$sapply(x, ~ u + 2 * v, v = 10)
## [1] 21 22 23

# same
fn$sapply(x, u + v ~ u + 2 * v, v = 10)
## [1] 21 22 23

# same
sapply(x, function(u, v) u + 2 * v, v = 10)
## [1] 21 22 23
```

**2) magrittr**

The [magrittr package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=magrittr) supports a pipe notation for defining single argument functions.  The argument must be dot.

```
library(magrittr)

x <- 1:3
sapply(x, . %>% {.})
## [1] 1 2 3

# same
sapply(x, function(x) x)
## [1] 1 2 3

# same
x %>% sapply(. %>% {.})
## [1] 1 2 3
```

**3) lambda.r** The [lambda.r package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=lambda.r) allows one to define *named* functions using `%as%`.  Here we define a function named `fun`.

```
library(lambda.r)

x <- 1:3
fun(x) %as% x
sapply(x, fun)
## [1] 1 2 3

# same
fun <- function(x) x
sapply(x, fun)
## [1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

The 'wrapr' package provides several ways to abbreviate anonymous functions. On a LINUX platform (it depends on the OS and the locale to allow the lambda character to be a "letter" available for naming a symbol),you can do such things :

```
library(wrapr)
λ <- lambda
sapply(1:10,λ(x,x^2))
#[1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100

λ(x,y,x*y)(6,7)
#[1] 42
```

Answer (score 2):

- The `pryr::f` function allows very compact function definitions, it guesses the arguments of the function from the expression that you feed to it, it works well for simple calls.
- `purrr` uses `purrr::as_mapper`, which itself calls `rlang::as_function`, so you can call those as well, it's not much less verbose though.
- [I wrote a package called lambda](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/lambda) that makes the formula notation compatible with base R (or any package with minor setup), it's in progress but totally usable already. For interactive use only, don't program with it.

---

*examples :*

### f

```
aggregate(. ~ Species, iris, pryr::f(mean(range(.))))
#      Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1     setosa         5.05        3.35         1.45        0.35
# 2 versicolor         5.95        2.70         4.05        1.40
# 3  virginica         6.40        3.00         5.70        1.95
```

### as_function

```
aggregate(. ~ Species, iris, rlang::as_function(~mean(range(.))))
#      Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1     setosa         5.05        3.35         1.45        0.35
# 2 versicolor         5.95        2.70         4.05        1.40
# 3  virginica         6.40        3.00         5.70        1.95
```

You can assign it to a short variable for compact syntax:

```
.. <- rlang::as_function
aggregate(. ~ Species, iris, ..(~mean(range(.))))
```

### as_mapper

```
aggregate(. ~ Species, iris, purrr::as_mapper(~mean(range(.))))
#      Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1     setosa         5.05        3.35         1.45        0.35
# 2 versicolor         5.95        2.70         4.05        1.40
# 3  virginica         6.40        3.00         5.70        1.95
```

### lambda

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/lambda")
library(lambda)
attach_lambda()
aggregate(. ~ Species, iris, ~mean(range(.)))
#      Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1     setosa         5.05        3.35         1.45        0.35
# 2 versicolor         5.95        2.70         4.05        1.40
# 3  virginica         6.40        3.00         5.70        1.95
```

---

Additionally functions like `base::Negate`, `base::vectorize`, `purrr::partial`, `purrr::compose`... can help to make the code more compact sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure any sensible R programmer should take serious offence at the following, but for a bit of fun this seems to work, and does away with the chore of having to call a function that is 6 letters long

```
s=function(x,f)
{
    eval(parse(text = paste('y <- function(x)',deparse(substitute(f)),collapse='')))
    sapply(x,y)
}
```

So now `s` is used instead of `sapply`.

```
s(1:3,x*2)
## [1] 2 4 6
```

*x must be used as the function's single argument, this is likely to be as buggy as hell.*