# Transposing list of long datasets to single wide dataset

Tags: r, list

I have a list Counts_L,length 65, of long datasets, like below:

Counts_L[[1]]

| Freq | Idx_names |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | A |
| 200 | B |
| 300 | C |

Counts_L[[2]]

| Freq | Idx_names |
| --- | --- |
| 150 | A |
| 2000 | C |

and I want to change this into a single wide dataset Counts_W with 65 rows, one for each dataset in the original Counts_L:

Counts_W:

| Freq_A | Freq_B | Freq_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 300 |
| 150 | 0 | 2000 |

I'm thinking to write a function that identifies the missing "Idx_names" and fill it in with a zero "Freq" value, and then use "map" to somehow extend this to all the datasets in the list and then merge them, but so  far had no success. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may combine all the dataset in a single one and get it in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bind_rows(Counts_L, .id = "id") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Idx_names, values_from = Freq, 
              names_prefix = "Freq_", values_fill = 0) %>%
  select(-id)

#  Freq_A Freq_B Freq_C
#   <int>  <int>  <int>
#1    100    200    300
#2    150      0   2000
```

`id` variable here creates a unique number for each dataframe in `Counts_L` list.

```
bind_rows(Counts_L, .id = "id")

#  id Freq Idx_names
#1  1  100         A
#2  1  200         B
#3  1  300         C
#4  2  150         A
#5  2 2000         C
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
Counts_L <- list(structure(list(Freq = c(100L, 200L, 300L), Idx_names = c("A", 
"B", "C")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
    Freq = c(150L, 2000L), Idx_names = c("A", "C")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! yes, my bad, I should've made a dataset, rather than just display it. What is the variable "id" in bind_rows doing - it's not there in the original data? Thanks again!

Comment: I added an explanation in my answer for the "id" variable. I would suggest to run the code line by line to understand what each step does.  @user2450223

Answer (score 2):

One option is to `pivot_wider` on each table and then `bind_rows`, which is tolerant of missing columns in some of the `data.frame`s, but will fill those with `NA`. Then it looks like you want to fill missing values with `0` so you can use `mutate(across())` to run `replace_na` on everything:

```r
library(tidyverse)

counts_l <- list(
  data.frame(freq = c(100, 200, 300), idx_names = LETTERS[1:3]),
  data.frame(freq = c(150, 2000), idx_names = c("A", "C"))
)

counts_l %>% 
  map(\(x)x %>% pivot_wider(names_from = idx_names, values_from = freq, names_prefix = "freq_")) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), \(x) replace_na(x, 0)))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   freq_A freq_B freq_C
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1    100    200    300
#> 2    150      0   2000
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: What is \(x)? I have not seen this before? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: It's a shorthand syntax for an anonymous function introduced in R 4.1. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52492462/13210554) post for details. Same for `.x` in Darren's answer.

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` solution with `tibble::deframe()` + `purrr::map_dfr()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

Counts_L %>%
  map_dfr(~ deframe(select(.x, 2:1))) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace_na(.x, 0), .names = 'Freq_{.col}'), .keep = "unused")

# # A tibble: 2 × 3
#   Freq_A Freq_B Freq_C
#    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1    100    200    300
# 2    150      0   2000
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What is ".x"? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Using `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
 dcast(rbindlist(Counts_L, idcol = "id"), id 
  ~ paste0("Freq_", Idx_names), value.var = "Freq", fill = 0)[,-1]
   Freq_A Freq_B Freq_C
1:    100    200    300
2:    150      0   2000
```